# Is scientific writing equal to research paper writing?

Tags: technical-writing, research, scientific-publishing

I am just not sure if scientific writing is same as research paper writing.

Comment: It can probably also be book writing.

Comment: You mean Scientific Writing is basically a broad Umbrella and under which Research Paper Writing can take place?

Comment: Yes, I think so. https://sites.middlebury.edu/middsciwriting/overview/ puts it like this: "Scientific writing is a technical form of writing that is designed to communicate scientific information to other scientists". So that can be research papers, or books, even research proposals and posters at a conference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "research paper" is used in various ways. As taught in US High schools, it ius a sort of apprentice version of an academic paper, mostly in one of the humanities. A scientific report of experimental findings is significantly different in form and content, although it might be called a "research paper", it is certainly reporting the results of a kind of research. Scientific research reports by experimentalists have a very strict and specific format, the details of which differ based on the specific field and often sub-field of science involved. A paper in sub-nuclear physics will not look much like one in sociology. But in general there will be an introduction indicating the nature of the problem or issue to be addressed; a review or prior work and existing theories in the area; a discussion of the experimental design and methods; a report of the findings; and a conclusion interpreting those findings.

A theoretical paper will look rather different again. discussing current theories and proposing some change or refinement to them. In some fields such papers are highly mathematical, in others not so much. Such a paper may discuss the results of various experimenters  or other primary data.

Both "Scientific Writing" and "Research Paper" are vary broad terms that include quite a few different forms of writing. Some kinds of writing might be referred to by either term. Some would not.

Comment: Thanks, @David Siegel. This was helpful.